# Nested query score explain

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to explain a score to a stakeholder, everything is fine except for one nested score which I don't know where is coming from,

Here's my nested query:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "path": "Blogs",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "Blogs.Content": {
                "query": "natural language processing",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "Blogs.Title": {
                "query": "natural language processing",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the explain from server:

```
{
  "value": 27.200674,
  "description": "Score based on 3 child docs in range from 555905 to 556048, best match:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 36.431717,
      "description": "sum of:",
      "details": [
        {
          "value": 16.900509,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 6.0398054,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Content:natural in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 5.6280847,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Content:language in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 5.232618,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Content:processing in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": 19.531208,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 6.6028557,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Title:natural in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 6.6028557,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Title:language in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 6.3254976,
              "description": "weight(Blogs.Title:processing in 68490) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                {...}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is: How is the score 27.200674 calculated given that the sum of the matches is 36.431717? No formulas have been included in the query.